# Problem to fill cards in TailWindCSS on large displays and less cards

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, tailwind-css

please, I have grid which looks fine on mobile and desktop. But on large displays I want 4 maximum columns. But currently I have only 3 tabs. It's possible please grow these 3 columns fill to `container` class width in **TailWindCSS**?

You know, it doesnt' look nice.

Otherwise, I can use flexbox of course. This I tried as well but then I need last card align to left side an all other cards must be centers which is impossible in flexbox.

3 requirements:

1. Max 4 columns in one row (no problem - solved)
2. Fill less than 4 columns in large display to full width of container
3. In small display (640px for width which means any mobile in landscape) must show 2 cards (not just one)

Problem 1 and 3 is solved. But about problem 2 please? It's possible solve it with tailwind CSS or I need own special classes?

Here is example of my code with one card:

```css
@tailwind base;

body {
  @apply bg-gray-900;
}

@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .main {
    @apply min-h-screen mx-auto;
  }

  .card-container {
    @apply grid pt-3 gap-3 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4;
  }

  .card {
    @apply rounded-lg overflow-hidden bg-gray-100 text-black shadow md:shadow-xl lg:shadow-2xl;
  }

  .site-header {
    @apply text-white text-center text-2xl font-bold p-10 bg-white bg-opacity-20 rounded-md;
  }

  .card-image {
    /*@apply object-cover max-h-96 w-max filter grayscale;*/
    @apply object-cover w-96 h-96;
  }

  .card-header {
    @apply flex m-2 font-semibold;
  }

  .card-title {
    @apply mt-3 text-lg font-medium uppercase text-center;
  }

  .card-description {
    @apply px-5 h-80 overflow-y-auto;
  }

  .card-labels {
    @apply bottom-0 flex space-x-1 m-2;
  }

  .card-labels-item {
    @apply text-center text-xs font-semibold px-3 py-1 rounded-md border-2 border-gray-800;
  }

  .btn-vote {
    @apply inline-flex items-center border-2 border-black w-20 rounded-md mr-2 px-1;
  }
}

.thumbup {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20 20' fill='black'><path d='M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z' /></svg>")
    left center no-repeat;
}

.thumbdown {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20 20' fill='black'><path d='M18 9.5a1.5 1.5 0 11-3 0v-6a1.5 1.5 0 013 0v6zM14 9.667v-5.43a2 2 0 00-1.105-1.79l-.05-.025A4 4 0 0011.055 2H5.64a2 2 0 00-1.962 1.608l-1.2 6A2 2 0 004.44 12H8v4a2 2 0 002 2 1 1 0 001-1v-.667a4 4 0 01.8-2.4l1.4-1.866a4 4 0 00.8-2.4z' /></svg>")
    left center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<main class="container main">
  <section class="p-3">
    <h2 class="site-header">A-Z Planet</h2>
    <div class="card-container">
      <!-- First card -->
      <article class="card">
        <figure>
          <img class="card-image" src="https://zrebec.sk/assets/alpaka.jpg" alt="" />
        </figure>
        <header class="card-header h-8">
          <a href="#" class="btn-vote">
            <div class="h4 w-4 mr-1 thumbup">&nbsp;</div>
            186
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="btn-vote">
            <div class="h-4 w-4 mr-1 thumbdown">&nbsp;</div>
            12
          </a>
          <div class="flex-grow font-bold w-100 text-right">84%</div>
        </header>
        <h2 class="card-title">Alpaca</h2>
        <p class="card-description">The alpaca is a camelid mammal native to South America. Closely related to its larger cousin, the llama, the two species are able to interbreed. Yarn spun from alpaca wool is popular for warm, soft sweaters, socks, mittens, and hats, making the fur of these domesticated animals a valuable commodity.</p>
        <footer class="card-labels">
          <div class="card-labels-item text-white bg-green-500">White soft fur</div>
          <div class="card-labels-item text-black bg-yellow-500">Cute but not domestic</div>
          <div class="card-labels-item text-black bg-red-500">Sometimes strange</div>
        </footer>
      </article>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Of course, you can look on my whole code on TailwindCSS Playground. Thanks

Best regards and thanks for any advice.

[Here is my code on TailWindCSS Playground][1]

Comment: If I understand correctly you are looking for grid repeat auto-fill/auto-fit, but is is not included in tailwind https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/ and https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/1403 and https://gist.github.com/iamazik/5aa934513388a6e48f44e63648a261d8

Comment: Solved, thank you very very much. This was help. I edit my artictle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have probably best solution.

In tailwind.config.js you should change `auto-fit` in `gridTemplateColumns` to this line:

```css
"auto-fit": "repeat(auto-fit, minmax(calc( 25% - 1rem ), 1fr))",
```

The row abowe means that auto-fit in gridTemplateColumns willl be minimum 25% - 1rem (becase gap between tables) which causes maximum 4 cards in xl or larger display and 1fr will be maximum size. This solution works if you will have just one card (will be maximum stretched) or if you will have 12 cards, then you will 4 cards for 3 rows.

then you can adjust your `.card-container` class into this one:

```css
.card-container {
  @apply grid grid-flow-row gap-4 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-auto-fit;
}
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

### SOLUTION

At the first, you must edit the config file for tailwind

```json
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      gridTemplateColumns: {
        'auto-fit': 'repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        'auto-fill': 'repeat(auto-fill, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      },
      gridTemplateRows: {
        'auto-fit': 'repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 1fr))',
        'auto-fill': 'repeat(auto-fill, minmax(0, 1fr))',
      },
    },
    variants: {},
    plugins: [],
  },
}
```

And finally edit you *card* container in your css:

```css
.card-container {
  @apply grid grid-flow-row gap-4 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-auto-fit;
}
```

And done. Thanks so much to [chojnicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10585773/chojnicki)